# how to make a loop for reading several nc files as a raster and then write them as envi?

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, rgdal, envi

This code given below ([developed by stackoverflow users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13700965/1451109)) will read a variable from a netcdf file and write it as an envi file.
This code is working fine but I have several netcdf files like this one and I want to make a loop to do this for all files in the directory.
The files are stored in a directory whose path is

```
d <-  flip(t(d), direction = "x") 
rf <- writeRaster(d, filename="last.envi", overwrite=TRUE)
```

I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:length(a)){
    d <- raster(a[i], varname = "soil_moisture_c")
    rf <- writeRaster(d[[i]], filename="%d.envi", overwrite=TRUE)
    }
```

but got this error

```
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable) : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"numeric", "character"’
```

Comment: why d[[i]]? change d[[i]] by d in writeRaster

Comment: @agstudy you could add this as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 bugs : change d[[i]] by d and use a new output file for each input.

```
 fileName <- strsplit(a[i],split='\\.')[[1]][1]
 outputFile <- paste(fileName,'_amenlast','.envi',sep='')
 rf <- writeRaster(d, filename=outputFile, overwrite=TRUE)
```

PS : I keep overwrite=TRUE , that means if you launch your loop next time it erase previous generated file.

Comment: `fileName <- strsplit(gsub("C:\\\\AMSER\\\\","",a[i]),split='\\.')[[1]][1]`?

Comment: @agstudy indeed, and he doesn't have to change his working directory, nice.

Comment: you can use one output file for 30 diffrents inputs files..do you get it?