# My map (in R) is upside down. How do I flip it back up?

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, flip

I have an .nc file that I'm trying to plot a map out of. I got my data here: https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.UDel_AirT_Precip.html (precip.mon.ltm.v301.nc). The latitude starts from `89.75` to `-89.75`. Longitude starts from `0.25` to `359.75`. This is what I did:

> File1<-Sys.glob("precip.mon.ltm*.nc")
>
> tmfile<-File1
>
> pr_file<-nc_open(tmfile)
>
> lat=ncvar_get(pr_file,'lat')
>
> lon=ncvar_get(pr_file,'lon')
>
> time=ncvar_get(pr_file,'time')
>
> precip=ncvar_get(pr_file,'precip')
>
> image.plot(lon,lat,precip[,,1],main="Precipitation")

Error in image.default(..., breaks = breaks, add = add, col = col) :
increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected

> lat1<-sort(lat)
>
> image.plot(lon,lat1,precip[,,1],main="Precipitation",zlim=c(0,20))

Then the map comes out, but upside down. ie, Antartica is on top. How do I turn my map the right way round?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when you're asking a question. The desired outcome in this case would help greatly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick hack is to flip the data itself.

```
image.plot(lon,lat,precip[,ncol(precip):1,1],main="Precipitation")
```

The lon and lat variables, i believe, also need to be defined differently as the error suggests, e.g.
(see [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353857/error-plotting-data-from-netcdf-file-increasing-x-y-values-expected)):

```
lon = seq(1, 360, length.out = nrow(precip)) 
lat = seq(1, 360, length.out = ncol(precip))
```

**Update:**
I, somehow, switched lat and lon. Please, try this now. And you will need to change the axes labels into something that would make sense.

[image: Precip]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your map's exactly what I want, but it's not working out too well for me. So I did:

> lat=seq(1,360,length.out=nrow(precip))

> lon=seq(1,720,length.out=ncol(precip))

> image.plot(lon,lat,precip[,ncol(precip):1,1],main="Precipitation")

And this is what I get:

Error in image.default(..., breaks = breaks, add = add, col = col) : 
  dimensions of z are not length(x)(-1) times length(y)(-1)

The image I get has lon and lat in different positions compared to yours, and there's no map on it either. Just a blank axis titled Precipitation. What's wrong?

Comment: It's alright, I got it. Just mixed up lat and lon's sequence. Thanks alot!