# R- plotting 2.5 grid netcdf data with country contour

Tags: r, plot, netcdf

I'm trying to plot precipitation data which has a 2.5 x 2.5 grid with the country contour on top, the data is available in this link: https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.cmap.html  "Mean (Enhanced Monthly)"

I was using the answer from: [R - Plotting netcdf climate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520837/r-plotting-netcdf-climate-data). However I get an error.

This is what I have done:

```
library(ncdf4)
ncpath <- "C:/Users/"
ncname <- "precip.mon.mean"
ncfname <- paste(ncpath,ncname,".nc",sep="")
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)

lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "lon")
nlon <- dim(lon)

lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "lat")
nlat <- dim(lat)

dname <-"precip"
ppt_array <- ncvar_get(ncin,dname)
dim(ppt_array)

pres <- ppt_array[ , ,25:444] 
precip <- array(pres, , dim=c(nlon, nlat, 12, ano)) 
prec <- precip[97:115,21:34, ,1:ano] #I just want a piece of the map
```

Here is where I have the problem:

```
latlat <- rev(lat)
precipit <- prec[ , ,1,1] %Just to see if it works
lonlon <- lon-180
image(lonlon,latlat,precipit) 
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl) 

#however I don't know if this will work to plot just a portion of the map  
plot(wrld_simpl,add=TRUE)
```

I get several errors, could someone please help?

EDIT:
The errors I got were these:

```
> image(lonlon,latlat,precipit)
Error in image.default(lonlon, latlat, precipit) : 
  increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected
> library(maptools)
> data(wrld_simpl)
> plot(wrld_simpl,add=TRUE)
Error in polypath(x = mcrds[, 1], y = mcrds[, 2], border = border, col = col,  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

Comment: Can you post all the error messages that you saw?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use package `raster` to handle simple netCDFs like this. It is so handy. The upcoming `stars` package will be even better, but it is still in heavy development.

Comment: I'll give it a try with the raster, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several things that need to be fixed:

1) `ano` does not seem to be defined anywhere. Perhaps it was defined interactively?

```
precip <- array(pres, , dim=c(nlon, nlat, 12, ano))
```

2) It appears you intended to add a comment but used an [infix operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12730629/9197650) instead - replace this with a `#`, like so:

```
precipit <- prec[ , ,1,1] # Just to see if it works
```

3) If you want to only have part of the map, you can either ensure that both the `lat` and `lon` arrays match the area that you want to show (essentially cropping the world map) or define NAs outside the region you want to highlight (which will appear similar to the map [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13700254/9197650))

Comment: You are right I forgot to copy it here, it's 35. 
Thank you for the link I'm gonna chek it out.