# My loop runs correctly and suddenly fails on a single file

Tags: r, loops, netcdf, netcdf4, hdf

I am attempting to open and plot about 60 netcdf4 files from a directory. I followed a similar example originally posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700254/the-variable-from-a-netcdf-file-comes-out-flipped)

```
"~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height"

ncfiles <- list.files("~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height")

for (i in 1: length(ncfiles)){
fname <-(paste0("~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/", ncfiles[i]))
 f <- nc_open(fname)
 print(fname)
}
```

When I run this section, the correct files are being read and printed to the screen but suddenly stops with this error message:

```
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T201241_20180715T215609_03908_01_010301_20190530T173144.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T215411_20180715T233739_03909_01_010301_20190530T174631.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T233541_20180716T011909_03910_01_010301_20190530T175745.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180716T011711_20180716T030038_03911_01_010301_20190530T181100.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180716T213507_20180716T231835_03923_01_010301_20190530T202107.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180716T231637_20180717T010005_03924_01_010301_20190530T203126.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180717T005807_20180717T024134_03925_01_010301_20190530T203847.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180717T211603_20180717T225931_03937_01_010301_20190530T231939.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180717T225733_20180718T004100_03938_01_010301_20190530T233047.nc"
[1] "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180718T003902_20180718T022230_03939_01_010301_20190530T234019.nc"
Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: HDF error
Error in nc_open(fname) : 
  Error in nc_open trying to open file ~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180718T205659_20180718T224026_03951_01_010301_20190531T015417.nc
```

I have opened the file highlighted by the error message outside of the loop so I don't believe the file is corrupt. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Using `try`, I am able to run the loop to completion and print all desired files to the console. The next step for me is read in the files, extract variables, and stack the raster images on top of one another resulting in a single image. `Try` and `TryCatch` are not working and my loop breaks as soon as the first error is encountered.

```
for (i in 1: length(ncfiles)){
  try(
    {
      fname <-(ncfiles[i])
      f <- nc_open(fname)
      print(fname)},
    silent = T)
  ah <- ncvar_get(f, varid = "DETAILED_RESULTS/aerosol_optical_thickness")
  lon <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/longitude")
  lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/latitude")
  nc_close(f)
  s1 <- data.frame(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah))
  crsLatLon <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
  ex <- extent(c(-180,180,-90,90))
  pmraster <- raster(ncol=360*10, nrow=180*10, crs=crsLatLon,ext=ex)
  pmraster <- rasterize(s1[,1:2], pmraster, s1[,3], fun=mean, na.rm=T)
  exHI <- extent(c(-180,-140,10,30))
  levelplot(crop(pmraster,exHI))
}
```

How can I modify my loop structure to skip the errors?

Comment: You probably need to add nc_close to your loop

Comment: Good point @RobertWilson, thank you. I believe that is necessary but even when I add that to my loop, the code produces the same error message.

Comment: Other than the file being corrupt, which you have said is not the case, I cannot see how this can be happening.

Comment: Does it always stop on a _particular_ file or just on the "n"th file?

Comment: It is happening on 6 particular files. But that is okay, I just need to skip them as they interrupt my end goal of creating a single image from all the files.